# Get list of active minor modes in buffer

Tags: minor-mode

How get a list of active minor modes in current buffer?

Docs `(info "(elisp)Minor Mode Conventions")` say:

```
 Define a variable whose name ends in ‘-mode’.  We call this the
 "mode variable".  The minor mode command should set this variable.
 The value will be ‘nil’ if the mode is disabled, and non-‘nil’ if
 the mode is enabled.  The variable should be buffer-local if the
 minor mode is buffer-local.
```

I ended with:

```
(dolist (m minor-mode-list)
  (when (symbol-value m)
    (push m modes)))
```

`describe-mode` sources have notes that:

```
;; Older packages do not register in minor-mode-list but only in
;; minor-mode-alist.
```

I don't know if that still valid point...

Comment: Doesn't `describe-mode` give you an adequate list of the active minor modes in the current buffer?

Comment: @Drew It sounds like he maybe wants it programmatically?

Comment: @nanny: Yes, I guessed that. In that cases, one place to start would be to look at the code for `describe-mode` - *if* that is otherwise adequate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested the `(mapcar #'car minor-mode-alist)` solution, but its length doesn't change after I disable a minor mode (while `M-x describe-mode` reflects this). Moreover, it seems inaccurate as I can't find some minor-modes listed by `M-x describe-mode`.

I tried the package [manage-minor-mode](https://melpa.org/#/manage-minor-mode) which allows users to enable/disable a minor-mode through an interface. `manager-minor-mode` doesn't have the issues aforementioned and here is the function it uses to look up active minor-modes:

```
(defun manage-minor-mode--active-list ()
  "Get a list of which minor modes are enabled in the current buffer."
  (let ($list)
    (mapc (lambda ($mode)
            (condition-case nil
                (if (and (symbolp $mode) (symbol-value $mode))
                    (setq $list (cons $mode $list)))
              (error nil)))
          minor-mode-list)
    (sort $list 'string<)))
```

Comment: Yeah, `minor-mode-list` & `minor-mode-alist` are just global registries. In order to filter buffer local enabled minor modes I think we need to check symbol value `NAME-mode` is `t`. The code you provided does this within expression `(and (symbolp $mode) (symbol-value $mode))` (though it checks for non-nil). Great idea, tnx!

Answer (score 19):

If you're just looking to see what minor modes are being used in a buffer, but don't need to use the list programmatically use:

`M-x describe-mode`

This command will open a new buffer that begins with a full list of your minor modes, as well as giving a brief description of the major modes, and any parent modes that may have been run.

Comment: While this may not exactly answer the question of the OP, this was the first result I found when searching for this question. Since Drew's comment solved my use case, I thought it deserved a full answer for future searchers.

Comment: +1 for demonstrating the more general purpose solution to the problem.  `describe-mode` is especially useful!

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```el
(mapcar #'car minor-mode-alist)
```

In fact, you will find that this value often differs from `minor-mode-list`.